# version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found on PowerPC (ppc64le) architecture

Tags: powerpc, rhel7, gcc8

I am on `rhel7.6 ppc64le`, trying to build a package. I have devtoolset-8 installed on my system. However when I try to test it, it gives the following error:

`/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /tmp/snappy7148417400130025252.tmp)`

I have tried the command `strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIB` which gives the following output:

`GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_LDBL_3.4
GLIBCXX_LDBL_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_LDBL_3.4.10
GLIBC_2.17
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH`

my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set to `/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/lib`. I have also tried changing it to `/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/lib/gcc/ppc64le-redhat-linux/8`.

Would like some help. I am running it on a High end VM with good connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to see full the link command.
Why are you using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?
Also, confirm you have `devtoolset-8-libstdc++-devel` installed.
`LD_DEBUG` can be used to produce a raft of related (and unrelated) debugging information.

```
LD_DEBUG=help /bin/true
```

... will show brief help text.

Comment: `devtoolset-8-libstdc++-devel` is already installed. `bash-4.2# ls -l /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx.` `1 root root 19 Feb 24 05:32 /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.19`. `libstdc++.so.6.0.19` file also exits.